# My library for 2 dimensional shapes

Tags: php, object-oriented, library

This is my first OOP PHP library and wanted to get advice on how I can improve what I wrote. This is what I needed to do:

I'm also not sure on what it meant by "proportionally resize the shape up or down, given a floating-point scale factor" I think what I did what it meant but I could be wrong.

> Build a simple PHP library for defining 2-dimensional geometric shapes and making basic calculations with them.
>
> For each shape, the library should be able to do the following:
>
> - calculate the area
> - calculate the perimeter
> - proportionally resize the shape up or down, given a floating-point scale factor

---

```
<?PHP
echo "Circle <br/>";
$circle = new circle(5);
$circle->getArea();
$circle->getPerimiter();
$circle->scale(up, .5);
$circle->getArea();
$circle->getPerimiter();

echo "<br/>Right Triangle <br/>";
$rt = new RightTriangle(4, 5);
$rt->getArea();
$rt->getPerimiter();
$rt->scale(up, .5);
$rt->getArea();
$rt->getPerimiter();

class Circle {
    public function __construct( $radius )
    {
        $this->radius = $radius;
    }
    public function getArea()
    {
        echo pow($this->radius, 2) * M_PI."<br/>";
    }
    public function getPerimiter()
    {
        echo 2 * M_PI * $this->radius."<br/>";
    }
    public function scale($direction, $scale)
    {
        if($direction == 'up')
        {
            $this->radius = $this->radius + ($this->radius * $scale);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->radius = $this->radius - ($this->radius * $scale);
        }
    }
}

class RightTriangle {
    public function __construct( $a, $b )
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function getArea()
    {
        echo ($this->a*$this->b/2)."<br/>";
    }
    public function getPerimiter()
    {
        echo $this->a + $this->b + sqrt(pow($this->a, 2) + pow($this->b, 2))."<br/>";
    }
    public function scale($direction, $scale)
    {
        if($direction == 'up')
        {
            $this->a = $this->a + ($this->a * $scale);
            $this->b = $this->b + ($this->b * $scale);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->a = $this->a - ($this->a * $scale);
            $this->b = $this->b + ($this->b * $scale);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **floating** point scale factor could control both magnitude and direction without the need for your $direction parameter.  If you want to double the size the $scale = 2.0, if you want to halve it the $scale = 0.5

and this is just personal preference if you were to stick with your $direction parameter in your scaling functions.  Create a static class constant so you don't have to hardcode 'up' and 'down' all over the place.

```
<?
    $circle = new Circle(5);
    $circle->scale(Circle::UP, 2);

    Class Cirlce {
        const UP = 'up';
        const DOWN = 'down';
    .
    .
    .
    }
```